# Share a folder between two Asp.Net web applications in the same solution

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm currently working on an Asp.net MVC Web application.
In my solution, there're two projects: front office and back office.
I'd like to share a folder that'll contain resources such as images, documents, etc... that'll be uploaded through the web application.

For example, when I upload an image using the back office, I only need to store the name of the image in my database, that way I'll be able to use this image in my front office part.
So I need to share a folder between both my applications.

Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two Applications, I think the best thing to do it is: To Create a new Virtual  Directory that maps to that folder(where the files are) into the second Application and then to write a HttpHandler that get the files from there.

Comment: I created a Virtual Directory in IIS and maps the folders of the front and back office to this directory.
This is not exactly what I wanted to do, but it works fine for now.

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a branch within your source control environment if that is what you're asking.

-Shaun